# Displaying different arrays of random images based on body id

Tags: javascript, random

I need to generate random images on refresh based on body id, basically each id has its own separate array of images that can be used. How would I write a script to do this?

Comment: Use a map like `var imgSet = {'id1': [array of iamges]}`, and get your images like `var imgs = imgSet[body.id]`.

Comment: you can declare differen backgrounds in the css for this. for example `#id1 .myClass {background-image: url(myid1.jpg);} #id2 .myClass {background-image: url(myid2.jpg);}` so you don't need js for this!